# Unable to connect to Mysql with Python code on external server [Ubuntu]

Tags: python, mysql, database, ubuntu

i want to connect MySQL in external server on Ubuntu. i already have Apache server in there and i have created table.i try to connect it form Raspberry Pi with python code but it doesn't work please help me

**Import part**

```
import bluetooth
import time
import mysql.connector
import MySQLdb
import os
import datetime
```

**Connection part**

```
#connect to db
db = MySQLdb.connect("133.2.206.154","kgam","password","kgam" )
#setup cursor
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM user"

try:
    # Execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute(sql)
    # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
    results = cursor.fetchall()
except:
    print "Error: unable to fetch data"
```

**Error**
  [This is my error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/125zY.jpg)

Comment: Did you set MySQL up to allow the `kgam` account to connect remotely?

Comment: i think i did but i'm not sure that i did it in the right way. Could you told me how to allow the account?  @RiggsFolly

Comment: Yea, you read the MySQL Manual